# Creating a 'universal' app in Android Studio for smartphones and tablets?

Tags: android, android-studio

I've been using Xcode for a few months now to create basic iOS applications. Within the startup settings, it allows you to select 'iPhone', 'iPad' or 'Universal'.

I usually setup my applications so that they are locked portrait on iPhone and locked landscape on iPad.

Firstly, how can I setup my project so that it is available to both smartphones and tablets when pushed to the Google Play Store?

Secondly, is there a way to set the orientation to portrait for smartphones and landscape for tablets?

Comment: Question is not clear, Are you asking how to programmatically set orientation in Android?

Comment: @shaheen - My apologies for being so vague. I guess it's classified as two questions. Will make an edit now.

Comment: No problem! I got it! I'll answer it now :)

Comment: I'd suggest you read how to design a [responsive UI](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/responsive-ui.html) - there's significant overlap between a large phone and a small tablet.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - The best thing here is that I'm actually using a webview to load my responsive website into the application. Hence having CSS take care of the responsiveness :)

Comment: @Fizzix - so then you shouldn't lock orientation at all, but instead transition from wide devices to narrow devices gracefully? Particularly small tablets are often used in both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is that the app should adopt its view according to whether the device is a phone or tablet. If so, Android provides a very good design called Master-Detail Flow. In a master/detail navigation flow, a master screen contains a list of items in a collection, and a detail screen shows detailed information about a specific item within that collection. And the beauty of it is that, in a phone it only shows the master view as a list and in a tablet it shows both master and detail in two panes. 
Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/descendant.html#) and [this](http://mobileappdocs.com/android.html)

Also for other adaptive UI see [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html)

Answer (score 0):

The concept of Android O.S is entirely different from iOS. Primarily, think of all the Android devices that exists! Lot of manufacturers, in different screen sizes and with varied configurations. However, an Apple iPhone is designed and manufactured by Apple, and it comes like a brick in different sizes. So it offers more of a robustness to the developer.

But in Android, due to it's versatility, there comes a need to design apps that runs equally same in all devices even with different screen resolutions. As a result, Android uses a technique called `DIP` Display independent pixels to address while designing. [[This]](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html) is the perfect place to get a structured knowledge on Android UI designing and scaling to different screen sizes.

Now coming to your second question, Android offers superior flexibility to the developers. And you can easily adjust the orientation programmatically:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE); //<-- Landscape mode
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //<-- Portrait mode
```

Hope this clearly answers your query!